# How to get UIButton position from UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have a `scrollView` with many buttons on it. I'm trying to get the Button position form the scroll so I can scroll it to that position. My issue is I always get the same value in `_btnV.frame.origin.x` once I click on each button. So please how I can resolve this issue?

```
- (void)scrollView{

    segmentWidth = screenWidth / 5;

    NSArray *images = @[@"Smiley-1.png",@"Smiley-2.png",@"Smiley-3.png",@"Smiley-4.png",@"Smiley-5.png",@"Smiley-5.png",@"Smiley-5.png",@"Smiley-4.png",@"Smiley-1.png",@"Smiley-2.png",@"Smiley-3.png",@"Smiley-4.png"];

    long ScrollContentSize = ((images.count -1)*segmentWidth)+screenWidth;

    _scrlView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(ScrollContentSize, _scrlView.frame.size.height);

    float screenX2 = screenHeight/2 - segmentWidth/2;

    __block float screenX = (screenWidth-segmentWidth)/2;

    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0; i<images.count; i++)
    {
        _btnV = [[UIButton alloc]init];
        [_btnV setFrame:CGRectMake(screenX, screenX2, segmentWidth, segmentWidth)];
        [_btnV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[images objectAtIndex:i]]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_btnV setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [_btnV addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollToMe:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [_btnV setTag:i];

        [arr addObject:_btnV];
        [_scrlView addSubview:_btnV];

        screenX = screenX+segmentWidth;
    }

    _menuItems = arr;

    [self.view addSubview:_scrlView];
}


-(void) scrollToMe:(id)sender{

    int scrollX = _scrlView.contentOffset.x;
    int mod = scrollX % segmentWidth;
    int position = scrollX/segmentWidth;
    float positionOffset = (float) mod / segmentWidth;

    scrollX = position * segmentWidth;

    NSLog(@"position:%f",_btnV.frame.origin.x);

    //scrollX = ...

    [_scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollX, scrollX) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: what is need to call `setContentOffset` in UIButton selector method. because you are `tapping` on `UIButton` means you are on this offset already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the button using its tag value

```
-(void) scrollTo:(id)sender{

    UIButton * button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int position = button.tag;

    scrollX = position * segmentWidth;

    NSLog(@"position:%f",_btnV.frame.origin.x);

    //scrollX = ...

    [_scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollX, scrollX) animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: It is woking great I didn't know that I should call the sender.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling selector method of `UIButton`. so in this method, you can directly get UIButton position with respect to `UIScrollView`. like

```
-(void) scrollTo:(id)sender{

    UIButton* btnClick = (UIButton*)sender;
    NSLog(@"X position : %f",btnClick.frame.origin.x);
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: let me know if you want some things different.

Comment: Your solution is as the answer below thanks again for your help. I didn't think that I should call the button sender. I vote +1

Comment: @CAN, kindy read my comment. i think there is no need of setContents in UIButton selector method.

Answer (score 0):

try this , it will log position of all your button correctly

```
 -(void) scrollTo:(id)sender{

    int scrollX = _scrlView.contentOffset.x;
    int mod = scrollX % segmentWidth;
    int position = scrollX/segmentWidth;
    float positionOffset = (float) mod / segmentWidth;

    scrollX = position * segmentWidth;
for(int i=0; i<images.count; i++)
{   if([[[_scrlView subviews] objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        Button btn = [[_scrlView subviews] objectAtIndex:i];
NSLog(@"position:%f",btn.frame.origin.x);
    }

}
    //scrollX = ...

    [_scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollX, scrollX) animated:YES];
}
```